# Ajax database search with bootstrap pagination

Tags: mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, search, bootstrap-4

I am building a live database search using Ajax. When the user updates the search form it posts the data and writes the result of the sql query to the tablebody. The page is styled using Twitter Bootstrap v4.

Currently pagination works through dynamically generated radio buttons inside the search form representing the page number. This sets the offset of the sql query so the correct rows are selected. However, this approach isn't pretty and I'd like to switch to Bootstrap's pagination.

Could I somehow combine the code for radio boxes with pagination with some clever use of labels and hidden inputs? Would it be better to have the pagination outside of the form, updating a hidden input representing page number when pressed? It would be more complex to keep track of the active page this way.

Are there any other best practices to follow when creating a live search?

A static version of my code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/strass/pen/JKQwqW). Here's the post request I use to send the data:

```
$.post('/clients/get/json', $("form#search").serialize(), function(res) {...}
```

Comment: for pagination you do not need form and radio buttons at all. Keep track of 
1. Total Pages,
2. Items to be displayed per page,
3. current Page number
4. When user clicks the page number button/link make AJAX call and let server do the calculation and return the result. The task of the UI should be to  just update result set.

Comment: @VishalAnand the form holds the search bar to filter by name. Currently everything needed for the sql query is folded into the form data and retrieved server-side using request.form (flask). Could I use get requests instead? I'd love a code sample, I'm not used to sending data through get requests.

Comment: What server side technology are you using ? You can use GET requests there is no problem in that but since you are posting other values also POST makes sense. Also, searching data and 'paging data' are two different concerns. Do not try to handle both in same way or in same request.

Comment: I am using flask (python microframework). Currently the search bar is an input in a form. My SQL query is `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE last_name LIKE :name OR CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, last_name) LIKE :name LIMIT 20 OFFSET :offset` `:name` comes from the search bar (`info['name']+'%'`) and `:offset` is `(int(info['page'])-1)*20`